# Is GLS (GBAS landing system) an RNAV approach?

Tags: instrument-procedures, gnss, performance-based-navigation

PBN which is contrast to conventional navigation consists of RNAV and RNP. And I know that general RNAV approach of IAP has up to 4 minima such as LPV, LNAV, LNAV/VNAV, and LP.

And I know that GLS approach is precision approach that use GBAS as well as GPS, but GLS approach procedure chart is separated with RNAV approach chart. I guess that GLS approach is RNAV approach because it use GPS system not conventional aids. Is it correct? is there any official document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is GLS an RNAV approach? Short answer is no. It is also *not* in the framework of PBN.

#### <strike>RNAV</strike> approach

Out of confusion the naming was not standardized, which led to more confusion. This will be fixed, from 1 Dec 2022 only the term RNP will be permitted for the minima you mentioned. ([ICAO Circular 336](https://www.icao.int/MID/Documents/2016/PBN%20SG2/2.PBN%20Charting%20-%20ICAO.pdf), starts at page 19)

#### RNAV?

It stands for a**r**ea **nav**igation, which is the ability to fly **any** course in an area, not bound by VOR radials for example.

#### GLS

GLS uses a ground augmented signal, anchor point, course, and slope, so it does just the one thing (like an ILS).

#### PA, APV, and NPA

Another reclassification will start to impact the older terms *precision approach, approach with vertical guidance,* and *non-precision approach.* There will be only two main types, A and B. Here's a Eurocontrol slide that breaks them down, and also shows that GLS is not in the PBN scope:

[image]
([eurocontrol.int](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/events/presentation/eliot-day%201-final-approach-operations-symposium-2017.pdf.pdf))

Last but not least in case any of the above is confusing, this big Airbus [presentation](https://www.icao.int/ESAF/Documents/meetings/2017/AFI%20FOSAS%202017/Day%203%20Docs/Day_3_PBN.pdf) (icao.int, Sep 2017) covers the history from conventional navigation to PBN and beyond, and also talks about the GLS.

---

Addendum based on comments:

- A 'conventional procedure' in the slide above includes NDB, LOC, [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localizer_type_directional_aid), VOR, ILS, with or without DME, and [MLS](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36320/14897) approaches. ILS and MLS would fall under PA / Type B.
- For how the GLS plots the approach, see: [How do GLS avionics plot an entire accurate approach path?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53273/14897)
- One of the things that sets the GLS apart from RNAV is the need for a ground component at the airport, the VHF Data Broadcast (VDB) transmitter.